# Script block in content_for :in_script doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The script block begins with `$('#map#{shop.id}').....` in `content_for :in_script` doesn't work.

```
def edit_country_fields_template(city, shop)
  content_tag(:div, :class => "item") do
    "<div id='map#{shop.id}' class='map'></div>".html_safe +
   if shop.geocoded?
         content_for :in_script do
           $('#map#{shop.id}').gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: #{spot.lat},
     longitude: #{shop.lng},
     html: '_latlng' },
     { address: '#{shop.address_geo}',
       html: '#{shop.name}<br/><a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=#{shop.address_geo}' target='_blank'>See Full Map</a>' },
      ],
      zoom: 16 });
          end
       end
  end
end
```

I have this helper called in my view `edit.html.erb` with `<%= edit_country_fields_template %>`. But I have problem having the script code below added inline in the script of the view file:

```
$('#map#{shop.id}').gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: #{spot.lat},
     longitude: #{shop.lng},
     html: '_latlng' },
     { address: '#{shop.address_geo}',
       html: '#{shop.name}<br/><a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=#{shop.address_geo}' target='_blank'>See Full Map</a>' },
      ],
      zoom: 16 });
```

The end result is `if shop.geocoded` is `true`, the script code above will be shown in my view as inline script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#map1').gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: -1.030503,
     longitude: 1.340594,
     html: '_latlng' },
     { address: '200 Good Street, California, United States of America',
       html: 'California Restaurant<br/><a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=200 Good Street, California, United States of America' target='_blank'>See Full Map</a>' },
      ],
      zoom: 16 });
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: and what you really want ? We can't fix code without know what do it

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post and made it clearer.

Comment: It still is not clear what you want, since there is no question in your post.

Comment: The script block in "content_for :in_script do" doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the javascript? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Comment: Hmm... doesn't work. I removing the "content_for :in_script do" and wrapped it around "<script type...> -script-code-here- </script>".html_safe, it shows in the source code, but the map doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content_for` does not output anything, but stores the HTML in a buffer for use in other places (like the header or footer of your page).

In your view or partial:

```
content_for :my_script do
  "abc"
end
```

Then in your layout:

```
yield :my_script
```

Without the `yield`, your `content_for` will not be displayed.